# Mapbox handle multiple GEOJSON files with loadURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I'm currently working on a map that's meant to load multiple layers from different sources based on a `config.json` file.

Each layer should also display a popup on click but for some reason I only get the popup for the last loaded layer.

I'm using the `ready` event on the layers to make sure all the data gets loaded and iterating through them using `.eachLayer` method before binding the popup but still no success and can't figure out what am I missing.

Please find below my code as well a reproduction on: [**plnkr.co**](https://plnkr.co/edit/l1WF3w5ZtUZho5TVeTWj)

```
var myMap = function(options) {
  var self = this;

  this.settings = $.extend({
    layersConfig: 'config.json',
    layerData: 'layer',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF0dGJsaXNzIiwiYSI6ImNpb3dwczBwZjAwOTh3OWtqOWZ1aG5ob3gifQ.Ot6GdtKew9u27TROm_4A6Q'
  }, options);

  this.map;
  this.layers;

  $.ajax({
    url: this.settings.layersConfig,
    cache: true
  }).done(function(data) {
    self.init(data);
  });
};

myMap.prototype = {
  init: function(data) {
    var self = this,
      settings = this.settings;

    L.mapbox.accessToken = settings.accessToken;

    var map = this.map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
      .setView([54.6, -2.3], 4);

    var popup = new L.Popup({
      minWidth: 250
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var featureLayers = this.layers = L.mapbox.featureLayer(null, {
        style: {
          weight: 2,
          color: data[i].color,
          fillColor: data[i].color,
          fillOpacity: 0.4
        }
      }).addTo(map);
      // load layers data
      featureLayers.loadURL(settings.layerData + data[i].layerId + '.json')
        .on('ready', function(e) {
          featureLayers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            // cache layer properties
            var layerProps = layer.feature.properties;
            // cache feature bounds
            var bounds = layer.getBounds().toBBoxString();
            // bind modal
            layer.bindPopup(showPopup(layer, bounds));
          });
        });
    }

    map.on('popupopen', function() {
      $('.zoom-to').on('click', function() {
        var array = $(this).data('zoom').split(',');

        map.fitBounds([
          [array[1], array[0]],
          [array[3], array[2]]
        ])
      });
    });

    function showPopup(popup, bounds) {
      var popupData = popup.feature.properties;
      var popupLabel = popupData.NAME;
      var popupStructure = '<div class="leaflet-popup-label">' + popupLabel + '</div><button class="zoom-to" data-zoom="' + bounds + '">Zoom to</button></div>'

      return popupStructure;
    }
  }
}

var map = new myMap();
```

Comment: Thank you for having reproduced your issue on Plunker! Please note that the basic step still requires to share your code directly in your question, so that people can see what you are talking about without having to rely on a 3rd party service only. See also [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Just replace `featureLayers.eachLayer` with `e.target.eachLayer` and the popup will show as desired.

Comment: Congrats for having found the solution by yourself! :-) and thank you for having reported it here as well. Please can you **accept** your own answer so that people know your issue is solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 .on('ready',...)
```

^ Has nothing to do with an AJAX call.

You need to perform actions after the ajax call is finished, that is, inside the AJAX callback.

Here:

```
  }).done(function(data) {
    /* do stuff */
  });
```

Comment: The `ready` event is used on the layers not on the AJAX call. Here's [Mapbox documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/)